# Apply drag gesture on Canvas line paths - SwiftUI

Tags: ios, canvas, swiftui, drawing

My requirement is to move the line paths drawn on Canvas using drag gesture.
Here is my code sample for the same.

```
@State var currentScale: CGFloat = 0.0
@State var finalScale: CGFloat = 1.0

Canvas { context ,size in
 for line in toolBarObj.lines.filter({$0.id == self.elevationId}) {
 let path = engine.createPath(for: line.points)
      context.stroke(path, with: .color(line.color), style: StrokeStyle(lineWidth: 
line.lineWidth, lineCap: .round, lineJoin: .round))
    }
   }
.scaleEffect(finalScale + currentScale)
.position(self.lineP)
.gesture(DragGesture(minimumDistance: 0, coordinateSpace: .local).onChanged({ value in
let newPoint = value.location
  if arrColors[counter] == Color.white {
     self.lineP = newPoint
  }else {
   if value.translation.width + value.translation.height == 0 {
                                                        
toolBarObj.lines.append(Line(points: [newPoint], color: arrColors[counter], lineWidth: 
1.0, id: self.elevationId ?? ""))
 }else {
let index = toolBarObj.lines.count - 1
                                                        
toolBarObj.lines[index].points.append(newPoint)
 }
}
})
).onChange(of: scenePhase) { newValue in
 if newValue == .background && arrColors[counter] == Color.white {
   toolBarObj.saveLine() // code for saving the lines in file manager.
 }
}
```

The model class managed for Line :-

```
struct Line: Identifiable, Codable {

var points: [CGPoint]
var color: Color
{
    get {
        customColor.color
    }
    set {
        customColor = CustomColor(color: newValue) // CustomColor is the class for 
    managing the line color
    }
}
var lineWidth : CGFloat
private var customColor : CustomColor
var id : String
init(points:[CGPoint], color:Color, lineWidth: CGFloat = 1.0, id: String) {
    self.points = points
    self.customColor = CustomColor(color: color)
    self.lineWidth = lineWidth
    self.id = id
}
}
```

I am stuck in the part where I need to change the location of a particular line instead of the entire canvas. Can anyone help me find the solution?